# Is affirmative hiring illegal in Germany?

Tags: germany, discrimination, sex-discrimination

Saw this ad: [https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/565648/women-in-tech-all-levels-at-sustainable-start-finn](https://web.archive.org/web/20220326160415/https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/565648/women-in-tech-all-levels-at-sustainable-start-finn)

With the headline: "Women in Tech - all levels - at sustainable start-up (f/x) - Munich or Remote"

Wondering if only hiring f/x would be legal in Germany?

Answer (score 4):

- No, it’s not legal, [§ 7 Ⅰ | 1 AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0047) (“employee” includes applicants, [§ 6 Ⅰ 2 AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0040)), *unless* the the job *requires* a certain sex, [§ 8 Ⅰ AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0051), example: porn actor. If you’re a *good* lawyer, you can argue that a women’s shelter hires *females* only, but only as far as the specific position includes interaction with patrons (i. e. janitor, or accountant must still be open to everyone).
- *Advertising* unwarranted gender-discriminatory positions is already illegal, [§ 11 AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0066). There are some people who abuse their legal rights and apply for such a position, include a discreet statement about their sex, and after receiving a rejection file a lawsuit for damages, [§ 15 AGG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0080), usually 3 months worth of wage.

Comment: This is a quite interesting case: that exact same employer currently has several job opportunities for similar jobs in *other* teams that are open to everyone. It is only *this one particular* job in *this one particular* team (the "Women in Tech" team whose purpose it is to promote women going into tech jobs) which requires a woman.

Comment: That one team might, because it is a promotional means, be exempt for the same reason why a woman shelter or waxing parlor can hire only women for customer-facing jobs.

Comment: @Trish What is the justification in accordance to § 8 ⑴ AGG for a tech position?

Comment: "The purpose of this job is not to produce a product but as an advertisement. Your job is to promote the fact that we hire female engineers." - How could a male fulfil *that* requirement?

Comment: @Trish Yeah, the problem’s § 11. You can’t post a discriminatory vacancy unless it’s justified discrimination. For that we’ll need a § 8 ⑴ justification, _zulässige Benachteilung wegen beruflicher Anforderungen_. It needs to an _occupational_ requirement, i. e. relate to your duties, what you do. As it stands the vacancy was for an engineer. For an engineer the sex is irrelevant. If it was _advertised_ as a _modeling_ position, it could be OK.

Comment: @Trish You could do § 5 AGG affirmative hiring, though. This typically manifests as a paragraph: _Employer E likes gender equality yadi-yada-yada. Provided qualifactions are the same, women are given preference._ (or _men_ whatever the sex‑ratio among current employees is). The advertisement may still not violate § 11, so the position must be open to all sexes, but _the selection process_ may include by way of an exception sex as a criterion.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt For an engineer *engineering* it is irrelevant, but for an engineer *recruiting women on job exhibitions* it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal as a rule, but might be allowed in special cases.

> Allgemeines Gleichbehandlungsgesetz (AGG) § 8
> Zulässige unterschiedliche Behandlung wegen beruflicher Anforderungen (1)
> Eine
> unterschiedliche Behandlung wegen eines in § 1 genannten Grundes ist
> zulässig, wenn dieser Grund wegen der Art der auszuübenden Tätigkeit
> oder der Bedingungen ihrer Ausübung eine wesentliche und entscheidende
> berufliche Anforderung darstellt, sofern der Zweck rechtmäßig und die
> Anforderung angemessen ist.

https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/agg/__8.html

Basically that says that if there is a job specific requirement to hire by race, gender etc that is not illegal for some other reason and is not a pure excuse to discriminate than you might get away with it. And organization that calls itself "[women in tech](https://women-in-tech.org/)" and aims to work against underrepresentation of women might have a relevant requirement to hire a woman for a specific position, since a man might be not able to credibly represent their values and purposes.

So as a rule not legal, might end up in court, but they might have arguments on their side that convince the court to rule in their favour.

Comment: Would an organization called "men in tech" be allowed?

Comment: Certainly, that is a free speech issue. If they would be allowed to hire discriminately is another matter, because they would have trouble convincing courts that men are underpresented in tech. "Men in minimum-wage part time jobs" would probably have better chances. Like I said, that is not a general rule, every attemt to discriminate during the hiring process would be under scrutiny, and in the end both parties would have to make their case in court.